# Issue with $.noConflict, jquery.cookie, and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-cookie

I am trying to use jquery.cookie to handle all of my cookie needs. Whenever I try to create a cookie, I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'cookie'`

I read to use `$.noConflict()` to fix this issue, which did indeed resolve the error above. However, when I use it, I get errors thrown about bootstrap's `.tooltip()`, as well as `$.sidr` which I use for my slide out menu.

Does someone have some suggestions on resolving this?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are incorrectly including multiple versions of jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially loaded jquery.cookie in the `<head>` of my site. Moving it to the very bottom fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you invoke noconflict mode you can no longer reference jQuery with `$`

I usually do it like this:

```
$j = jQuery
$j.noConflict();


$j(function(){

    $j('yourSelector').tooltip();

});
```

There is probably a more efficient way than duplicating the jQuery function, suggestions are always welcome

Comment: you aren't duplicating it, you're just storing a reference to it. But, it could be reduced to one line: `var $j = $.noConflict()` though, i question the need for having two versions of jquery to begin with.